# Geostationary Satellite Projection

Tags: coordinate-system

What is the equation needed for forward and inverse transformation of Geostationary Satellite projection.?. How to convert it to Geodetic and vice versa. Geostationary satellite projection is mentioned in Proj4 as [here](http://www.remotesensing.org/geotiff/proj_list/geos.html) and in [wiki](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/proj=geos)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a Geostationary Satellite:

- Occupy non-inclined geo-synchronous orbit.
- Always above same equatorial point.
- Location specified using longitude of the sub-satellite point and distance to the satellite.

So according to the [description](https://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/proj=geos) of the geos proj only required parameter you need to create a proj4 string is the height of the satellite:

`proj +proj=geos +h=35785831.0`

As an optional parameter you can add the

`+lon_0=`

as  the subsatellite longitude point in degrees. (a subsatellite point is the point which a line between the satellite and the center of the Earth intersects the Earth’s surface).

Those were the parameters concerning the geos projection. You can always if needed add any [general parameters](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/GenParms) to your string.

Answer (score 5):

Because PROJ.4 is released under an MIT license, you can easily find and study its source code. About Geostationary Satellite Projection: http://svn.osgeo.org/metacrs/proj/trunk/proj/src/PJ_geos.c

Comment: The straight link to the code is brilliant.